# Symlink Copy a Directory Non-recursively

Tags: symlink, cp

So I want to symlink copy all the files and folders in one directory to another directory. When I use `cp -s` though without the `-r` option I get a bunch of "omitting directory" warnings, and I don't want to omit directories:

```
$ cp -s /home/my_username/path_to_directory/* .
cp: omitting directory `/home/my_username/path_to_directory/foo'
cp: omitting directory `/home/my_username/path_to_directory/bar'
cp: omitting directory `/home/my_username/path_to_directory/baz'
```

If I use the `-r` option though, it symlinks all the files in the directories instead of symlinking the directories themselves.

How do I non-recursively symlink all files and folders in one directory to another directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out. I can't believe I didn't try this sooner:

```
ln -s /home/my_username/path_to_directory/* .
```